# log4j.xml logging not working in spring controller?

Tags: java, spring, logging, spring-mvc, log4j

I have placed the `log4j.xml` in `WEB-INF/classes/log4j.xml`.

My `log4j.xml` is ,

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!-- <!DOCTYPE log4j:configuration SYSTEM "log4j.dtd" > -->

    <appender name="fileAppender" class="org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender">
        <param name="Threshold" value="INFO" />
        <param name="MaxFileSize" value="512KB" />
        <param name="MaxBackupIndex" value="10" />
        <param name="File" value="F:/Spring_logs/pointel_Aop.log" />
        <!-- <param name="File" value="${webapp.root}/WEB-INF/logs/helloworld.log" /> -->
        <layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout">
            <param name="ConversionPattern" value="%d %-5p %c{1}:%L %m %n" />
        </layout>
    </appender>


    <!--sets the priority log level for org.springframework -->
    <logger name="org.springframework">
        <level value="info" />
    </logger>


    <!--sets the priority log level for com.pointel.EM.controllers -->
    <logger name="com.pointel.EM.controllers">
        <level value="debug" />
    </logger>


    <!--sets the default priority log level -->
    <root>
        <priority value="info"></priority>
        <appender-ref ref="fileAppender" />
    </root>

</log4j:configuration>
```

In my `web.xml` ,

```
    <context-param>
        <param-name>log4jConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/classes/log4j.xml</param-value>
    </context-param>

    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.util.Log4jConfigListener</listener-class>
    </listener>
```

In my `controller`,

```
@Controller
public class PageController {

    Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(PageController.class);

    @RequestMapping(value="index.html" , method=RequestMethod.GET)
    public String indexPage(){
        //logger.log(Level.DEBUG,"Entered in the GET of index.html");
        logger.trace("Trace..............");
        logger.debug("Debug...............");

        System.out.println("Index Page............");
        return "Main";
    }
}
```

The log file will be created in the specified location in the `log4j.xml`. But log information is not printed in the log file.

In the created log file,

```
2013-04-02 14:36:32,945 INFO  DispatcherServlet:301 FrameworkServlet 'dispatcher': initialization started 
2013-04-02 14:36:32,976 INFO  XmlWebApplicationContext:456 Refreshing WebApplicationContext for namespace 'dispatcher-servlet': startup date [Tue Apr 02 14:36:32 GMT+05:30 2013]; root of context hierarchy 
2013-04-02 14:36:33,023 INFO  XmlBeanDefinitionReader:315 Loading XML bean definitions from ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/dispatcher-servlet.xml] 
2013-04-02 14:36:33,367 INFO  DefaultListableBeanFactory:549 Pre-instantiating singletons in org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory@171f189: defining beans [org.springframework.context.annotation.internalConfigurationAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalAutowiredAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalRequiredAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalCommonAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.DefaultAnnotationHandlerMapping#0,org.springframework.format.support.FormattingConversionServiceFactoryBean#0,org.springframework.validation.beanvalidation.LocalValidatorFactoryBean#0,org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter#0,org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.MappedInterceptor#0,pageController,viewResolver,messageSource]; root of factory hierarchy 
2013-04-02 14:36:33,445 INFO  DefaultAnnotationHandlerMapping:411 Mapped URL path [/index.html] onto handler [com.pointel.EM.controllers.PageController@11db6bb] 
2013-04-02 14:36:33,445 INFO  DefaultAnnotationHandlerMapping:411 Mapped URL path [/Main.jsp] onto handler [com.pointel.EM.controllers.PageController@11db6bb] 
2013-04-02 14:36:33,445 INFO  DefaultAnnotationHandlerMapping:411 Mapped URL path [/addEmployee.html] onto handler [com.pointel.EM.controllers.PageController@11db6bb] 
2013-04-02 14:36:33,445 INFO  DefaultAnnotationHandlerMapping:411 Mapped URL path [/listEmployees.html] onto handler [com.pointel.EM.controllers.PageController@11db6bb] 
2013-04-02 14:36:33,476 INFO  Version:56 Hibernate Validator 4.0.2.GA 
2013-04-02 14:36:33,476 INFO  DefaultTraversableResolver:89 Instantiated an instance of org.hibernate.validator.engine.resolver.JPATraversableResolver. 
2013-04-02 14:36:33,632 INFO  DispatcherServlet:320 FrameworkServlet 'dispatcher': initialization completed in 687 ms
```

`Index page ........` will be printed in the console to confirm the entry of controller.

Can any one help to print the log information in the log file.

Good answers are definitely appreciated.Thank you .

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the setting for your controllers is not being applied:

```
<!--sets the priority log level for com.pointel.EM.controllers -->
<logger name="com.pointel.EM.controllers">
    <level value="debug" />
</logger>
```

See if changing the call from `debug` to `info` outputs.

```
@RequestMapping(value="index.html" , method=RequestMethod.GET)
public String indexPage(){
    logger.info("Info..............");

    System.out.println("Index Page............");
    return "Main";
}
```

Comment: Thanks it works now and `Info...........` is printed in log file . And can you say why ?

Comment: Listener defined Log4j ignores System.out.println and would only respond to logger.*****. That is why.

Comment: @Anand without seeing the entire project, I can only assume.  First, its apparent through my suggested test that the level for that logger is set to INFO.  I'm not sure if the root configuration is overriding the logger you established in the configuration or maybe the controller isn't within the package of the logger you specified.

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply...What to do if I need to print all the logging like `trace,debug,info,etc.....` ?

Comment: set priority to `all` for all loggers including the root

Comment: @Anand any other questions?